# xsl if conditon to display same level elements

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

How can i disply the same level element values after if conditon

For example

XML

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:if test="/catalog/cd/country='UK'">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
</xsl:if>
```

This will not displying the title and artist of UK level elements

I know that one way of solving it is to use for each loop but i am looking for an efficient method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using only templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/catalog/cd[country='UK']" priority="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/catalog/cd">
        <!--  handle non-UK CDs here -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are many other ways -- depending on your requirements, of course -- to arrange templates to generate your desired output. For example, you might end up with explicit templates for handling `title` and `artist` elements (or for explicitly hiding all other children of each `cd`).

All of this depends on your particular needs, but **the general point I wanted to show here is that you gain a lot of power (and end up with cleaner code) when you properly catch target elements in a template match** (instead of *ad-hoc* conditionals).

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/catalog/cd">
    <xsl:if test="country = 'UK'">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Hide your heartBonnie Tyler
```